# Hard disk is detecting as read only

Tags: linux, raid, debian-squeeze, ibm, operating-system

I am installing Debian Squeeze 2.6.32 64 bit OS in IBM System x3250 M4. This system is already having built in RAID. After enable the RAID, I have started to install the Debian Squeeze 2.6.32 64 bit OS. While doing the partition in the installtion, we are getting the hard disk as read only.

But we are able to install the RedHat successfully without any problem (no read only) .

Why we are unable to install the Debian Squeeze in the same machine. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try with the latest version of installation media (6.0.8 at the time of writing). Maybe you are missing some raid controller drivers, that are included in RHEL. Red Hat is known to backport drivers from newer kernels.

You can also try to install Wheezy.